# C code on X86 Platform : Call stack shows one function argument addres after the EBP register

Tags: c, assembly, x86, stack-overflow

I have a function with following definition:

```
void my_function(unsigned int a, unsigned int *b, unsigned c, unsigned d)
{
    ..........
}
```

The register info for this function looks like:

```
(gdb) i reg
eax            0xf42d4ea8       -198357336
ecx            0x0      0
edx            0x17e000 1564672
ebx            0xf8     248
esp            0xfffd46a0       0xfffd46a0          ---------------> ESP
ebp            0xffff4b48       0xffff4b48          ---------------> EBP
esi            0x1c     28
edi            0xffffd51c       -10980
eip            0x80911be        0x80911be <my_function+21>
eflags         0x286    [ PF SF IF ]
cs             0x23     35
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x2b     43
es             0x2b     43
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x63     99
```

---

Here I expect function arguments a, b, c, d to have addresses above the EBP register address 0xffff4b48 (Assuming stack grows from higher address to lower address). But I see for a, c, d have this as expected. But b has an address way below EBP.

The address in GDB shows as below:

```
(gdb) p &a
$15 = (unsigned int *) 0xffff4b50
(gdb) p &b
$16 = (void **) 0xfffd46fc    -----> How b is below EBP?
(gdb) p &c
$17 = (unsigned int *) 0xffff4b58
(gdb) p &d
$18 = (unsigned int *) 0xffff4b5c
```

The assembly code for this function looks like:

```
 0x080911a9 <+0>:     push   %ebp
 0x080911aa <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
 0x080911ac <+3>:     push   %edi
 0x080911ad <+4>:     push   %esi
 0x080911ae <+5>:     push   %ebx
 0x080911af <+6>:     sub    $0x2049c,%esp
 0x080911b5 <+12>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 0x080911b8 <+15>:    mov    %eax,-0x2044c(%ebp)
 0x080911be <+21>:    mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
 0x080911c4 <+27>:    mov    %eax,-0x1c(%ebp)
 0x080911c7 <+30>:    xor    %eax,%eax
 ==> 0x080911c9 <+32>:    movl   $0x0,-0x203ec(%ebp)
 0x080911d3 <+42>:    mov    0x20f305e4,%eax
 0x080911d8 <+47>:    cmp    %eax,0x8(%ebp)
 ................
 ................
```

Any possibility for this to happen?

Comment: Notice the type is wrong too. That means, you probably have a local variable also named `b` which shadows the parameter. Should have posted the C code.

Comment: I am sorry Jester. The code inside my_function() is too big. I made sure we don't have a variable of same name defined anywhere else in the function. One important thing i noticed is: In the assembly code:                    0x080911af <+6>:     sub    $0x2049c,%esp                                                    you can see ESP is pushed down by 0x2049c ~= 132k bytes. Also The pointer b at a time can only point to 132k, which is in shared memory (The shared memory size is much larger than that though). If I change this value to 16k, i see ESP is pushed down by 16K and not 132k.

Comment: I am not sure there is a deep copy of the memory from shared memory to function stack happening here. Otherwise how the stack size can vary depending on how much pointer b can point to.

Comment: `gdb` seems to think you do have a `b` of type `void*`.  I could reproduce the behavior that way.  Also check what the value of `b` is (is it the expected value for the argument?).  Try `info frame` and `p b`. If you don't provide more code, we can only guess.

Comment: (gdb) i frame
     Stack level 0, frame at 0xffff4b50:
     eip = 0x80911c9 in my_function (source.c:4580); saved eip     0x878f3e3
 called by frame at 0xffff4b90
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffff4b48, args: a=1, b=0xf42d4ea8, c=20, d=764
 Locals at 0xffff4b48, Previous frame's sp is 0xffff4b50
 Saved registers:
  ebx at 0xffff4b3c, ebp at 0xffff4b48, esi at 0xffff4b40, edi at 0xffff4b44, eip at 0xffff4b4c

Comment: I don't have a stack overflow as such. b is pointing to correct shared memory address.

Comment: (gdb) p &b
$16 = (unsigned int **) 0xfffd46fc    -----> How b is below EBP?

Comment: If you modify `b`, does gcc spill it back to the argument slot on the stack, or does it save it to a new location inside the function's stack frame?